# Align div with the top of a container

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have an unordered list styled to display horizontally. One of the li elements contains a div element. This div element is filled using ajax, though it shouldn't matter.

The div element has a larger height than the rest of the li elements, and by default it aligns with the bottom of the parent container.

Update: Well, isn't this awkward. I coded a simpler example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bfp3K/, and it works properly. I have to check my code again to get the error in the sandbox.

Update2: It wasn't that easy after all. I have added my proposed (and used) solution.

Update3: Disregard the previous answer, it wasn't correct. This is a simplified and testable example of the problem:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bfp3K/10/

CSS:

```
#one {
    background-color:red;
}
#two {
    background-color:green;
}
#three {
    background-color:yellow;
}
#four {
    background-color:blue;
}
.normal {
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;

}
.big {
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    display:inline-block;
}

ul {
    display:block;
}

ul li{
    display:inline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>

<li><div id="one" class="normal">One</div></li>
<li><div id="two" class="normal">Two</div></li>
<li><div id="three" class="normal">Three</div></li>
<li><div id="four" class="big">
    The last div vertically aligns to it's content's last line of text. I want to align the top of all the colored divs.

</div></li>
</ul>
```

Images:

What the solution should look like:
[image: Accetable solution]
What the problem looks like:
[image: Current Problem]

Comment: can you post some of your current html and css please?

Comment: No code, can't help...

Comment: Nice. You can always answer your own question haha

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just replace the `display:inline-block;` declarations with `float:left;` Since you're specifying the dimensions anyway, you don't need `inline-block`. The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bfp3K/13/) works and here's a pic. 
[image]

```
.normal {
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    float:left;}

.big {
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    float:left;}
```

Comment: While this solves the problem in jsfiddle, in my project most of the divs are dynamic and don't have specific dimensions.

Comment: Well if you remove the specific dimensions from the jsFiddle, you'll still get the same result: all tops aligned. Also, when you ask a question, it helps to include every aspect that applies.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your time :) I had complex code before, based on the code I used. I couldn't post the code because it is part of a tomcat web application.

Could you comment on the use of vertical-align:top instead of float:left? It seems to work, but I fear that adding the code could have side effects. (It is obvious I just started web development)

Comment: vertical-align:top is just for table cells; it doesn't work with divs. Float:left means "this div goes to the left of the previous element". If you don't put a float then a div will go below the previous element.

Comment: Check the fiddle in the answer I posted.
Also, floating left seems to ignore padding and margins I have set for the li elements.
(Again, thanks!)

Comment: Which fiddle? you have 2 of them.

Comment: It looks like you have no padding or margin defined.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32603/discussion-between-gcon-and-frenchie)

Comment: I have accepted this solution based on @frenchie advice that vertical-align:top is used for tables and not for div elements, making the latter not standards-compliant.

Comment: What?  The vertical-align property is for table-cell (controls vertical alignment of children) *and* inline elements (controls vertical alignment in relation to its siblings).  To say that it's "not standards-compliant" to use on divs is simply not true.  Change the display type and you're free to use it.

Comment: Well yes, you can change the display type of a div to table-cell, or table-row, and then you're using the vertical-align property on a div as if it were a table related element. May be "not standards-compliant" was not the right wording but overall using vertical-align on divs is ugly; you shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 9):

The solution was **very** simple after all. Based on another answer:

```
li div{
    vertical-align:top;

}
```

Since the elements have *display:inline-block;*, adding vertical-align:top seems to solve it. I won't mark this as the solution in case this isn't the proper solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/dv3Mm/

Answer (score 2):

updated (bottom-aligned):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
li {
    display:inline-block;
}
.item {
    vertical-align: bottom; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>Text 1</li>
    <li><div class="item">Text 2<img src="some.jpg"/></div></li>
    <li>Text 3</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: all texts would be top-aligned

Comment: This, in fact worked, just by changing vertical-align:bottom to vertical-align:top. From what I understand this is bad practice when used on non-table elements.

Answer (score 1):

Set the LI's `line-height` to the same pixel height of the image.

Comment: I tried this first, because it was the simplest to test. When the div only contains a link (sign in), it is displayed lower than the other items.
After creating a test on jsfiddle, I see that the default behavior is what I am looking for - and have broken this behavior with some of my code.
I can't find what could be causing it.

Comment: My code is tomcat based. I will try to save an signed out and signed in version and upload links.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 (quick and dirty):** 
set a `margin-bottom: [negative value here]` 
or `bottom: [negative value here]` if your `li` are relatively positioned and the div is absolutely positioned. This is assuming that you know exact values.

**Solution 2:** 
I'm assuming that the text in the other elements are links. 
Set top and bottom padding to those links (specifically the `<a>` tags, so that they are vertically aligned in the middle)

**Solution 3 (a bit more html):**
Put two divs in each li. Wrap the div you already have in another div again. Use the a vertical centering method (such as the tabel-cell method) to vertically center all the inner divs. http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html
(The `li` tags you already have might already work as the outer div wrap, but I'm not sure. didn't get to test that yet)

Answer (score 0):

In the code posted in the question the LIs have display: inline, and in the jsfiddle 'simpler example' their display is reset to inline-block (via classes). Inline-block is different from inline that it isolates any block-level content (like DIVs) inside, while attempting to put something block-level into inline causes the inline element to break into several so called [anonymous block boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level). May be this is the reason?